# Failed to find:com.android.support:design:22.2.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-developer-api

I used support design library in my project,but there is a error that it is not found.My android Studio has updated Android Support Library 22.2

> compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

this is my first time use of support design library.can somebody help me?

Comment: Update your Android SDK.

Comment: @Jared Burrows My Android Studio SDK had update to Android M (22)

Comment: What about the support libs?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Support Library 22.2

Comment: may be your studio is offline .Try disable offline mode in settings->build->gradle.

Comment: Go to Project > Rebuild project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the android support Repository in the SDK manager .
Also the Design Library depends on the Support v4 and AppCompat Support Libraries.

Reference:
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Answer (score 2):

Jared Burrows is right, need update SDK ( support library )

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered from this error, the solution was to open the android sdk and from extras install android support repository.
but on the most recent version android support repository does not exist you have to install local maven repository support library. i hope this will help you.